# How to find this telescoping Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{50} \frac{n}{n + n^2 + n^4} \\$?

Tags: partial-fractions, telescopic-series

Find the Telescopic Sum of :-

$$\sum_{n=1}^{50} \frac{n}{n + n^2 + n^4} \\$$

What I tried :- The denominator easily gets factorised to $n(1 + n + n^3)$ and the $n$ cancels out, leaving $\frac{1}{1 + n + n^3}$ , but from here I cannot factorise $1 + n + n^3$ , also I tried using partial fractions but without success . I have no idea how to do this.

Any explanations or hints to this problem will be appreciated !!

Comment: I don't think there is a telescoping solution for this sum.  Plus, the fact that the summands are $\dfrac{n}{n+n^2+n^4}=\dfrac{\color{red}n}{\color{red}{n}\,\left(1+n+n^3\right)}$, where $n$ cancels out, is a red flag (may be not red, but at least yellow) to me that there is something not right about the problem statement.  Most *nice* questions are not written like this.  There might be a typo.

Comment: Did you try partial fraction? (Not sure if that'll work)

Comment: $1 + n + n^3$ definitely should have one real root.

Comment: I agree with @Batominovski 100%. My guess is that the question was supposed to be about the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{50}\frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4}.$$ With that denominator there is some hope.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029773/find-s-n-if-t-n-fracn1n2n4) the actual question?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20, how did you find its duplicate so quickly?

Comment: @SarGe, You may now research on your own: [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) and [search engine](https://approach0.xyz) there's a lot of related stuff. Thanks to Martin Sleziak.

Comment: So, I actually got this question from a friend . I too agree that this has some problems, as I tried in many different ways to solve it, but couldn't do it. Had it been $$ \sum_{n=1}^{50} \frac{n}{1 + n^2 + n^4} \\$$ , I am sure that it could have been done easily by partial fraction decomposition , also @UmbQbify-Key20- , that's not a duplicate of this .

Comment: Seems like there is no other [way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+m%3D1+to+50+%28m%2F%28m%2Bm%5E2%2Bm%5E4%29%29)